# EF missing where clause in update

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

```
var row = DataContext.TableA.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Col1 == "foo" && x.Col2 == "bar");
row.Col3 = "xyz";
DataContext.SaveChanges()
```

I expected `Col3="xyz"` to be updated only for `Col1="foo" and Col2="bar"`. But it updated more rows that I expected. When I logged the queries, EF generated query seems to be missing `Col2` altogether. Any idea why?

```
UPDATE [dbo].[TableA]
SET [Col3] = @0
WHERE ([Col1] = @1)

-- @0: 'xyz' (Type = String)

-- @1: 'foo' (Type = String)
```

Comment: What is PK in `TableA`?

Comment: It is a composite of `Col1` and `Col2`.

Comment: are you using code-first? are you sure that you mapped entities correctly?

Comment: Yes, code-first. This is the mapping. `HasKey(x => x.Col1);
 Property(x => x.Col1).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
 HasKey(x => x.Col2);
 Property(x => x.Col2).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
 ToTable("dbo.TableA");`

Comment: your mapping is not correct. It should be `HasKey(m => new { m.Col1, m.Col2 });`

Comment: Thanks, you are absolutely right! That fixed it!!! What is the difference between the way you specified and the one I did?

Comment: I am glad that it helped :) I am adding it as answer. Please edit your question to show mappings. It is just the way it was designed to work. I suppose, there must only one `HasKey` method for mapping )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using *Fluent API* to specify *composite primary key* you must use `new` keyword to create anonymous type.

```
HasKey(m => new { m.Col1, m.Col2 });
```